# Calculate the 'economic significance' of a quadratic term?

Tags: logistic, simulation, odds-ratio, polynomial

I am calculating the "substantive significance" of my most important independent variable in my logistic regression. Using a simulation to assess the strength of my independent variable for my dependent variable, I follow the process of seeing how a one standard deviation change in my independent variable changes the probability of my dependent variable. I am stuck, however, because contrary to the few examples on the internet, I do not have a linear, but a linear and a quadratic term of the same variable.

My results look s.th. like this (leaving aside any other covariates):

```
              Odds ratio  Standard error
Variable      1.25        0.01
Variable ^2   0.95        0.01
```

And I know that "Variable" is on a scale from 0 to 5 and has a standard deviation of 2. "Variable^2" has a standard deviation of 20.

Now, in a linear model, I would now calculate `(1.25 + 2)*2.5 = 3.25*2.5` (2 for the standard deviation of "Variable" and 2.5. as the mean value of "Variable") and then see how the probability of my dependent variable changes (in comparison to the original model of `1.25*2.5`).

But how do I do that if I include a linear and a quadratic term of "Variable"? Would I then go:

`3.25*2.5 + 20.95*2.5` ?

I am very grateful for any help.